# Why I can't show and edit double\floated values into this JQuery view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I am very new in C#/.NET and JQuery view development and I am finding some difficulties trying to create input form to show and modify double values.

I have the following situation, into my view I have this input form:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="Severity">Severity:</label>
    <input type="number" id="Severity" name="Severity" min="0" max="10" step=".1" value="@Model.Severity))" />
</div>
```

The value of the **Severity** field of my model object (**@Model.Severity**) is: **3.0** (I checked it using the debugger) but this value is not shown into my previous input tag.

The severity field is declared as double value into my model object, in this way:

```
public double? Severity { get; set; }
```

Why it can't correctly work?

I am thinking that maybe is a formattation\internazionalization problem because I see that other views use the **,** character for the floatted number (3,0 instead 3.0)

What canI do to fix this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score -1):

Well thats because there is a extra closing angular braces `')'` in the value which is being set to the `severity` fld

Replace

`<input type="number" id="Severity" name="Severity" min="0" max="10" step=".1" value="@Model.Severity))" />`

with

`<input type="number" id="Severity" name="Severity" min="0" max="10" step=".1" value="@Model.Severity)" />`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: No, I still have the same problem :-(

Comment: @AndreaNobili: can u added `runat="server"` to your field, since its executed at server scope

Comment: This is the code, i have tested and working fine,  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="Severity">Severity:</label>
    <input type="number" id="Severity" name="Severity" min="0" max="10" step=".1" value="@Model.Severity" />
</div>